# Using string.erase() making a string longer?

Tags: c++

I ran into this issue on accident while debugging a faulty string trim function and now I'm wondering what exactly is causing this behavior.

Here's a code snippet with just the relevant bits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void debug(string s) { cout << "Len: " << s.length() << "; Value: '" << s << "'" << endl; }

int main()
{
    string str = "ABC";
    debug(str);

    str.erase( str.begin() + 4, str.end() );  // Magic!
    debug(str):

    return 0;
}
```

You'll notice that the erase function is taking an iterator that starts just beyond the end of the string.  This isn't the exact input used when I ran into the issue (it was having a +1 which broke empty strings), but it has a similar effect.  Here's the output:

```
Len: 3; Value: 'ABC'
Len: 4; Value: 'ABC '
```

When I change the `str.begin() + 4` to something greater like `+ 10` it becomes clear that I'm starting to pull in garbage data.

My question is: how is it that using the erase() function ends up making the string *longer* than before?  Also, is it just luck, or is the next character after the end of the string always whitespace?

Comment: The outcome from invoking undefined behavior is not always described as "luck".

Comment: You defined an invalid begining iterator.

Comment: debug into your own implementation of std::string and see what it does and why it does it. That won't happen with every implementation though because it is undefined behaviour, i.e. there is no fixed behaviour for doing this (and your program could crash)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`string::erase()` has the following precondition:

- Requires: first and last are valid iterators on *this, defining a range [first,last)

since your code doesn't hold to this, it's exhibiting undefined behavior.  There's not a whole lot of point in analyzing why it breaks something - basically the `erase()` function is making an assumption that's not true.

But if you're really curious about exactly what's going on you would at least need to specify which tool chain you're using (since UB varies quite a bit depending on the compiler and library). It would probably be easiest to just step through the code in a debugger to see why it's behaving this way in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

Passing invalid iterators is undefined behavior.  Anything could happen.

Comment: The OP should count himself lucky that he didn't cause Godzilla to attack Tokyo! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
str.erase( str.begin() + 4, str.end() );  // Magic!
```

This invokes undefined behaviour, because `str.begin()+4` points to beyond `str.end()`, as `str.size()` is `3`.

That means, anything can happen : nothing is guaranteed by the language, nor by the compiler.

Comment: Unless he's got the library debugging turned on (which should be the case, until the profiler tells him that he can't).